# How to replace multiple string with multiple value with shell script in text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a text file in that some fields are there like

{ 9,-october,c
23,-November,e
56,-monday,t }

I want to replace "october" with "oct" ,"November" with "nov" and "monday" with "mon" . 
Searching pattern value may be in both case(upper or Lower).
I dont have any idea of shell.. otherwise i will tell you what am i have coded..

this should find all in .txt file.  Please help me with script.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service, what's your *question*?

Comment: Have a look at `sed`.

Comment: If you do not know a certain programming language, and need a problem to be solved, you have three choices: (1) Learn the language. (2) Use a language which you know. (3) Hire a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something simple like

```
cat your-textfile | sed 's/october/oct/g' | sed 's/November/nov/g'
```

If this works for you, further improvements can be made later.